# Cakephp database session

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am trying to configure database session, so I added these lines to app.php

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
        'timeout'  => 8032, 
        'cookieTimeout' => 10 * 8032, 
    ],
```

And I have created the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` ( 
  `id` char(40) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL, 
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- optional, requires MySQL 5.6.5+ 
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- optional, requires MySQL 5.6.5+ 
  `data` blob DEFAULT NULL, -- for PostgreSQL use bytea instead of blob 
  `expires` int(10) unsigned 
  DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

But I still get this error:

> Fatal error: [Cake\ORM\Exception\MissingTableClassException] Table class for alias `Sessions` could not be found

What am I doing wrong?

***MORE INFORMATION***

CAKEPHP VERSION: 4.2.3

StackTrace

```
[Cake\ORM\Exception\MissingTableClassException] Table class for alias `Sessions` could not be found. (/var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:245) #0 
/var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/Locator/AbstractLocator.php(62): Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->createInstance('Sessions', Array) 
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php(205): Cake\Datasource\Locator\AbstractLocator->get('Sessions', Array) 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Session/DatabaseSession.php(62): Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->get('Sessions', Array) 
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Session.php(274): Cake\Http\Session\DatabaseSession->__construct(Array) 
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/sr in /var/www/vhosts/domain/ShopManagment/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 196
```

Comment: It is ok, according to the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions). My first guess is that you aren't connecting to the host or schema you have your table created

Comment: Depending on your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), and in which environment you receive that error (please always include the related stacktrace), this error can have different meanings/causes!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the directions say there is a schema for the Sessions table included with the CakePHP files. Double check that your schema is correct for the version of Cake you're using. Make sure you can log into MySQL and browse that table.

Also, are there any associations created with this Session table? Because the alias problem often lies with association arrays?

Comment: Your answer is not an answer - Its a comment / request for more information. It belongs in the comments.